# How to set user image in parse cloud code

Tags: php, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have the following cloud code on parse to update a user image but I can't seem to get it saving. help!

```
in php
ParseCloud::run("updateUserImage", array("file" => $_FILES['image'], "objectId" => $objectId, "name" => $_FILES['image']['name'], "type"=> $_FILES['image']['type'] ));


in cloud code
Parse.Cloud.define("updateUserImage", async (request) => {
const { file, objectId, name, type} = request.params;

var fileData = request.params.file;
var fileSave = new Parse.File(name, fileData);
fileSave.save();

var User = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User);
var query = new Parse.Query(User);
let result = await query.get(objectId, { useMasterKey: true });
if (!result) new Error("No user found!");

result.set("profilePicture", fileSave);
try {
result.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
return "User updated successfully!";
} catch (e) {
return e.message;
}
});
```

Comment: Try with `await fileSave.save();` and `await result.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });`

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick unfortunately

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: my page i sent the ajax call to just shows an error page in browser

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: I just get HTTP ERROR 500 page

Comment: You need to find a way to find more details about the error either in your parse server logs or in your php application. Otherwise it will be pretty hard for someone to help.

Comment: Hi all, I was able to accomplish this via currentUser saving rather than cloud code. This will be fine for me at this point. Thanks!